# SVN Copying Trunk To Branch, Copies Trunk Folder Too?

Tags: svn

I am using the following code to copy a trunk to a branch:

```
svn copy svn://web/path/to/trunk \svn://web/path/to/branches/dev -m "Creating a dev branch of trunk"
```

It seemed to work fine except it moved the folder trunk along with it.  For example:

trunk/somefile.html was copied to branches/dev/trunk/somefile.html

Is this normal?  I assume that it shouldn't be like that and would like to know how to copy the branch correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you created the branch ( basically a folder ) named dev under branches? If you had done that, it will copy trunk under dev. If the dev was not existing already, it will be like trunk folder was copied as dev folder, the way you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you! Makes total sense.

Comment: Hello Sir, could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36157555/3287204)? Thanks in advance ... :)